# code not detecting ads7830 even though i2cdetect shows the address

Tags: pi-3, i2c

I am trying to run `Motor.py` code from `Freenove`. I can see that my `ads7830` IC is up and running

```
i@raspberrypi:~/Freenove_Kit/Code/Python_Code/13.1.1_Motor $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 4b -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

But when I run my code, I get error that I2C address can't be found. Why?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Freenove_Kit/Code/Python_Code/13.1.1_Motor $ python Motor.py 
Program is starting ... 
Not found device in address 0x48
Not found device in address 0x4b
No correct I2C address found, 
Please use command 'i2cdetect -y 1' to check the I2C address! 
Program Exit.
```

Address detection code is

```
def __init__(self):
    super(ADS7830, self).__init__()
    self.cmd = 0x84
    self.address = 0x4b # 0x4b is the default i2c address for ADS7830 Module.

def analogRead(self, chn): # ADS7830 has 8 ADC input pins, chn:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    value = self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, self.cmd|(((chn<<2 | chn>>1)&0x07)<<4))
    return value
```

The code which calls the above check is

```
def setup():
    global adc
    if(adc.detectI2C(0x48)): # Detect the pcf8591.
        adc = PCF8591()
    elif(adc.detectI2C(0x4b)): # Detect the ads7830
        adc = ADS7830()
    else:
        print("No correct I2C address found, \n"
        "Please use command 'i2cdetect -y 1' to check the I2C address! \n"
        "Program Exit. \n");
        exit(-1)
```

Comment: What is printing "Not found device in address 0x48" ?

Comment: Are you using PCA9685 (or PCF9591, or ...? https://github.com/Freenove/Freenove_4WD_Smart_Car_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/blob/master/Code/Server/Motor.py

Comment: sorry, I had made a mistake in wiring. Hadn't connected VCC input to power.